# Eloquent JavaScript chessboard

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, ascii-art

Is this a good way to solve the quiz "Chessboard" from http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html ?

> Write a program that creates a string that represents an 8×8 grid, using newline characters to separate lines. At each position of the grid there is either a space or a “#” character. The characters should form a chess board.
>
> When you have a program that generates this pattern, define a variable size = 8 and change the program so that it works for any size, outputting a grid of the given width and height.

This is my code:

```js
 size = 10; 
    
    grid = ""
    
    for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
      for (var j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
         grid+= "# "
        } else {
         grid+= " #"
        }
      }
      grid+= "\n"
    }
    
    
    console.log(grid)
```

Comment: You put a '#' and a space in each 'cell'. The problem you posted says space OR '#'. So for each iteration of the inner loop, it should be `grid += "#";` or `grid += " ";`

Comment: This code produces a board that is larger than the size specified in the challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fun question;

- you should write a function that takes a parameter instead of just writing the code
- A chessboard has lots of repetition, take a minute to ponder how [String.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) could make this code much simpler.
- Your indentation is not perfect, consider using a site like http://jsbeautifier.org/
- I am not a big fan of `var` within the loop, I would declare `var` up front.

This is a possible solution that provides the right size of the board:

```
function createChessboardString(size){

  const line = ' #'.repeat( size ),
        even = line.substring(0,size),
        odd = line.substring(1,size+1);
  let   out = '';

  while(size--){
    out = out + ((size % 2) ? odd: even ) + '\n';
  }

 return out;
}

console.log(createChessboardString(8));
```

You could consider for very large boards that the board in essence repeats 
`odd + '\n' + even`, so you could `repeat` that as well. The problem for me is that there are too many corner cases to consider. So personally I would go for the above for any board size < 1000.

Comment: one question: I changed the code to `(i + j) % 2 === 0` because i took a look in the solution. Could you please explain me this? Why adding these together? @konijn

Comment: I would have to see the surrounding code, plus that is not really what codereview is about. I was just thinking that your code seems wrong actually. If ' ' is white and '#'' is black, then your board is way too big.

Comment: @konijn why are you not a fan of `var` within the loop?

Comment: Cant find back the exact location, but it's in there: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#variables basically js hoists those variables anyway to the top

Comment: Your codeuses very incon sistentspacing.